# Why $\cos(x \cdot \imath)$ is a real number while $\sin(x \cdot \imath)$ is a complex number?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Wolfram Alpha gives following results for $\cos(i x)$ and $\sin(i x)$ ,where $x\in\mathbb{R}$:

$\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$

$\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x)$

What is a reason why the first number is real while the second is complex ?

Definition of the $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ may be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_algebraic_expressions).

Comment: Say that $f$ is **real** if $\overline{f(z)}=f(\overline z)$. Then, if $f$ is real and even, it's real on $i\mathbb R$, and if $f$ is real and odd, it's imaginary on $i\mathbb R$. - That's basically what Zev spelled out.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using dotless i's for the imaginary unit? Just curious.

Comment: @Henning,no special reason...you may edit and put $\mathrm{i}$ if you like so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that, using [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry), we can conclude that
$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
and
$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}.$$
Thus,
$$\cos(ix)=\frac{e^{-x}+e^{x}}{2}=\cosh(x)$$
and
$$\sin(ix)=\frac{e^{-x}-e^{x}}{2i}=i\left(\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}\right)=i\sinh(x),$$
and it is clear from the definitions that $\sinh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$ are both real for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $\cos(ix)$ is real for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $\sin(ix)$ is imaginary for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is directly related to the graphs of cosh and sinh: cosh is parabolic, while sinh drops off to negative y values when x is negative: This (-x,-y) portion of the sin graph could be taken as suggestive toward the role sin plays in representing imaginary numbers. Conversly the (-x,+y) values of cosh is representative of the role it plays as a carrier of positive/real numbers. If cosh had (-x,-y) values it would likely also carry imaginary components.

[image]